# SQL Server TIME to XML ISO8601 value

Tags: sql-server

How to convert SQL TIME field to XML duration value so it looks like "PT72H" instead of "23:11:12"? Tried CONVERT(VARCHAR, value, 126) - wrong result. 
Thanks!

Comment: But `23:11:12` *isn't* a duration of 72 hours, as `PT72H` is. A SQL `TIME` is just the time of day without a date, not a duration in the sense of ISO 8601. Your conversion can be done, but makes sense only if you're (ab)using `TIME` to store durations of less than 24 hours. Are you? (An `INT` or `BIGINT` column with duration in seconds/minutes/hours/whatever you want would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to what you're literally asking, converting a `TIME` into an ISO 8601 duration (which corresponds to the `xs:duration` type of XML schema):

```
DECLARE @t TIME = '23:11:12';
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('PT$hH$mM$sS', 
    '$h',DATEPART(HOUR, @t)),
    '$m',DATEPART(MINUTE, @t)),
    '$s',DATEPART(SECOND, @t))
;
```

```
PT23H11M12S
```

If you need to include milliseconds:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('PT$hH$mM$s.$fS', 
    '$h',DATEPART(HOUR, @t)),
    '$m',DATEPART(MINUTE, @t)),
    '$s',DATEPART(SECOND, @t)),
    '$f',DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @t))
;
```

The problem with this is that the `P` format of ISO 8601 indicates a *duration*, not a *point in time*. While you could pretend `TIME` indicates a duration from the start of a day, it isn't capable of representing any duration larger than 24 hours, so you may have a mismatch between what you have and how you're representing it.